# Why does my bound List<T> return empty using foreach loop to display values on razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

In my razor page PageModel I have a bound `List<T>` property:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<JobCard> CustomerSpecificJobCards { get; set; }
```

Here is the JobCard model:

```
public partial class JobCard
{
    public int JobCardId { get; set; }
    public string Products { get; set; }
    public string CusCode { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public bool IsAssigned { get; set; }
}
```

The list of `JobCards` is populated after the user posts an order number from the page:

```
CustomerSpecificJobCards = AllJobCards.Where(jc => jc.CusCode == WorkOrderInfo.MarkForCusCode).ToList();
```

It is then displayed in a form on the razor page via a `foreach` loop:

```
@foreach (var card in Model.CustomerSpecificJobCards)
{
    <div class="col-1"><input asp-for="@card.IsAssigned" /></div>
    <div class="col-9">@card.Products</div>
    <div class="col-2">@card.JobCardId</div>
}
```

Users are shown a list of job cards and a checkbox. Once checked the user submits the selections. When I look at the `CustomerSpecificJobCards` that are posted, the list is empty. Why? Based on [information here](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2533), I decided to change the `foreach` loop to a `for` loop:

```
@for (var card = 0; card < Model.CustomerSpecificJobCards.Count; card++)
{
    <div class="col-1"><input asp-for="@Model.CustomerSpecificJobCards[card].IsAssigned" /></div>
    <div class="col-9">@Model.CustomerSpecificJobCards[card].Products</div>
    <div class="col-2">@Model.CustomerSpecificJobCards[card].JobCardId</div>
}
```

[EDIT] Originally, I thought all the values were returned using the `for` loop, but it turns out only the `.IsAssigned` values are returned... `Products` and `JobCardId` are empty. I'm using Razor Pages for the first time. What am I doing wrong?

[Followup] After reading Rafalon's answer, I [found this explanation](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes#collections-of-complex-objects) of binding a complex collection with checkboxes in either a for or foreach loop. Plus, here is another [excellent related link on data binding](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp.net-mvc-getting-default-data-binding-right-for-hierarchical-views).

Comment: show the controller code and the model etc

Comment: Because `asp-for` uses the variable name to create the `name` and `id` of the input, and it needs to be indexable (e.g. `<input name='CustomerSpecificJobCards_0__IsAssigned' id='CustomerSpecificJobCards[0].IsAssigned' />` - check the generated html). Same goes for mvc when you use `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Property[index].Subprop)`, you need a `for` and not a `foreach` loop

Comment: `@Model.CustomerSpecificJobCards[card].Products` this is just text, if you want it returned, you need it to be an input (be it hidden - `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Model.CustomerSpecificJobCards[card].Products" />` - or not) - same goes for `JobCardId`

Comment: Is see. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: check the generated HTML for both `for` and `foreach` and you'll see that with `foreach`, you can not expect the form to return the `List` correctly (with `asp-for` helper).

`for` is needed so you get indexable inputs, looking like:

```
<input name='CustomerSpecificJobCards[0].IsAssigned'
         id='CustomerSpecificJobCards_0__IsAssigned' />
```

You could still do it with `foreach`, but without `asp-for` it's quite tedious, and your model have to meet some requirements (having an index property for example).

---

Your other problem comes from the fact that `@Model.CustomerSpecificJobCards[card].Products` is text only.

Therefore you should either replace it with an `input`, just like `IsAssigned`, or else you can add a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Model.CustomerSpecificJobCards[card].Products" />
```

Same goes for `JobCardId`.

Comment: Thanks. Here is more helpful info showing checkboxes using both a for and foreach loop: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes#collections-of-complex-objects

Comment: Yes that's it, `asp-for` takes what you give it to generate the `name` property, so if you use `foreach`, you have to specify the `name` yourself (and then well you can't use `asp-for` so you also have to specify the `value`)